# Android AVD Problem

Tags: android

I just created a android AVD which runs on the 3.1 version. After it starts running, it takes a lot of time to move from one activity to another. Is there any way I could speed up this process.

Comment: i m also facing this problem, i was found many blog, forum, article for it. but i cant got success.. but i got only one conclusion and it is increase your ram size upto 1GB in emulator

Comment: This post https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/5tsU92tJbOE/CJv9OKveMKcJ from David Turner does a lot to explain why it's so slow... essentially, software emulating graphics for a tablet sized display is inefficient, as is software emulating an MMU.

Comment: From the fire side chat at Google I/O I recall them saying that they will ship out a better simulator in 3.2

Comment: @Chris: That was a fantastic link.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators will always run much slower than the devices. Anyhow, the android emulators now are much faster than before, so make sure you keep your sdk updated (and you obviously have, since you're running 3.1).

Also, I consistently noticed that emulators running in ubuntu 11 are faster than the same emulators in Win 7 (same hardware), so you might want to give ubuntu a try.

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator takes a lot of memory while it's starting up. It's normal. The thing you can do here is using a feature called snapshot. Snapshot will save your time (and probably resources) from the start booting up.

Read this article for more details:
[Optimizing Apps for Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html)

under the "About Emulator Performance" section.

Hope it helps.